# What is the proper way to set a dictionary value which is a reference type to null?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Let us suppose we have a class like below :-

```
        class DoubleLinkedListNode
        {
            public int Value { get; set; }

            public DoubleLinkedListNode(int value)
            {
                Value = value;
            }

            public DoubleLinkedListNode next = null;

            public DoubleLinkedListNode prev = null;
        }
```

And then we create a dictionary as given below :-

```
IDictionary<int, DoubleLinkedListNode> dict = new Dictionary<int, DoubleLinkedListNode>();
```

The `key` of the dictionary will hold the `Value` of the `DoubleLinkedListNode` that it contains like this :-

```
DoubleLinkedListNode newNode = new DoubleLinkedListNode(value);
dict.Add(newNode.Value, newNode );
```

Let us also create a function which takes the type of the value of the dictionary as input and we make that value `null` inside the body of the function as shown below :-

```
private void RemoveNode(DoubleLinkedListNode nodeToBeRemoved)
{
     if(nodeToBeRemoved != null)
     {
         //Do Something

         nodeToBeRemoved = null;
     }

}
```

and we call the function like this :-

```
RemoveNode(dict[someValue]);
```

Let us create another function in which we make the value `null` explicitly as shown below :-

```
    private void RemoveNodeAnother(DoubleLinkedListNode nodeToBeRemoved)
    {
         if(nodeToBeRemoved != null)
         {
             //Do Something
             dict[nodeToBeRemoved.Value] = null;
         }

    }
```

And then we call the function like this :-

```
RemoveNodeAnother(dict[someValue]);
```

What is the difference between the above two functions ?

Why I am asking is this I was doing [this question](https://leetcode.com/explore/featured/card/30-day-leetcoding-challenge/531/week-4/3313/) on Leetcode. The solution that I wrote is as follows :-

```
public class FirstUnique 
{
    private class DoubleLinkedListNode
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }

        public DoubleLinkedListNode(int value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public DoubleLinkedListNode next = null;

        public DoubleLinkedListNode prev = null;
    }

    DoubleLinkedListNode dummyHeadNode = new DoubleLinkedListNode(-1);

    DoubleLinkedListNode dummyTailNode = new DoubleLinkedListNode(-1);

    IDictionary<int, DoubleLinkedListNode> dict = new Dictionary<int, DoubleLinkedListNode>();

    public FirstUnique(int[] nums) 
    {
        InitialiseDummyHeadAndTailNodes();

        foreach(int i in nums)
        {
            Add(i);
        }
    }

    public int ShowFirstUnique() 
    {
        return dummyHeadNode.next.Value;
    }

    public void Add(int value)
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(value))
        {
            RemoveNode(dict[value]);
        }
        else
        {
            DoubleLinkedListNode newNode = new DoubleLinkedListNode(value);

            AddNode(newNode);

        }
    }

    private void InitialiseDummyHeadAndTailNodes()
    {
        dummyHeadNode.next = dummyTailNode;
        dummyTailNode.prev = dummyHeadNode;
    }

    private void RemoveNode(DoubleLinkedListNode nodeToBeRemoved)
    {
        if(nodeToBeRemoved != null)
        {
            nodeToBeRemoved.prev.next = nodeToBeRemoved.next;
            nodeToBeRemoved.next.prev = nodeToBeRemoved.prev;

            // If I write nodeToBeRemoved = null, the solution won't pass.
            // But if I write dict[nodeToBeRemoved.Value] = null, the solution is accepted.

            dict[nodeToBeRemoved.Value] = null;
        }

    }

    private void AddNode(DoubleLinkedListNode nodeToBeAdded)
    {
        //Update the pointers.
        nodeToBeAdded.prev = dummyTailNode.prev;
        nodeToBeAdded.prev.next = nodeToBeAdded;
        nodeToBeAdded.next = dummyTailNode;
        dummyTailNode.prev = nodeToBeAdded;

        //Add the node to the dictionary.
        dict.Add(nodeToBeAdded.Value, nodeToBeAdded);
    }
}
```

I have made the comments where the anomaly lies. What could be the reason for this behavior ?

Comment: The scope of `nodeToBeRemoved` is the `RemoveNode` method and this is a pointer to the actual `DoubleLinkedListNode` if you `null` that pointer (`nodeToBeRemoved = null`) all you do is point that local pointer to nothing. Your `Dictionary` still holds another pointer to the object so nothing changes and the entry will keep existing. As for correctness I can't say much since the leetcode link requires you to be logged in.

Comment: Exactly as @Knoop said. This is why modifications to *properties* of `nodeToBeRemoved` (like `node.next`) will be reflected in the dictionary node, because they're both referring to the same object. But *assignment* is a different story - after `nodeToBeRemoved = null;`, the dictionary value and the local node are no longer referring to the same thing.

Comment: For what it's worth, you may want to look at the [`Dictionary.Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.remove?view=netcore-3.1) method if you no longer need the key value (it's the counterpart to the `Add` method, where both the key and value are removed). It's not clear to me what the dictionary is for, except possibly a faster way to lookup a node than walking the list (in which case I don't think you'd need the `key` for a `null` value).

Comment: For [this question](https://leetcode.com/explore/featured/card/30-day-leetcoding-challenge/531/week-4/3313/), I need the key but not its value if I have encountered that key more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one way to "set dictionary value to null" -

```
 dictionary[key] = null;
```

indeed, if key is not there you need to add it first... Which leads to *the way to set value to null* -

```
 if (dictionary.ContainsKey(key)) 
        dictionary[key] = null;
 else
        dictionary.Add(key, null);
```

Note that setting value to `null` has *zero* impact on what was stored there previously.